# Does (or did) any monarchy have a limited length of tenure?

Tags: monarchy

[Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy) about monarchies states that they might have "predetermined limits on the length of their tenure". However reading the page there is no mention about any current monarchy who does that.

So, do any current monarchy have such a system, either a simple "time limit" or something more complex? Voluntary abdication doesn't count, obviously.

If not, are there any (recent or ancient) notable examples of monarchies with such a rule?

Comment: [This](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/monarchies-with-built-in-rotation) question (monarchies with built-in rotation) seems related too.

Comment: As phrased, I'm tempted to migrate this question to politics.se.

Comment: @T.E.D. Since I guess that likely there aren't any contemporary monarchies with such a rule, I guess history is more appropriate. But feel free to migrate if you're sure it would be in-scope there even if it was about ancient monarchies... _(I edited accordingly)_

Comment: [Related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9295/why-are-there-always-2-vampire-elders-that-are-in-hibernation) :)

Comment: Visigoths are the closest I can think of , but they didn't have predetermined terms - just deposed kings at the will of a councel.

Comment: Various regents, such as the [Empress Dowager Cixi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_Dowager_Cixi), may (partly) fit the question.

Comment: Related question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/monarchies-with-built-in-rotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only modern day examples of monarchies with limited tenure are Malaysia and the United Arab Emirates.

"There are two elective monarchies, Malaysia and the United Arab Emirates, where the constituent states of each federation are hereditary monarchies but those rulers form an electoral college which assigns the federal position of head of state to one of their number for a term (of five years)."

source: [Wiki page on Hereditary Titles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_title)

There are some other examples in there as well of some more ancient monarchies.

Comment: This is more "rotational" than and actual single-ruler limit, but I guess there are none of those, then.

Answer (score 6):

I'll look at non hereditary absolute rulers first, which are similar to monarchies. If you look up [Dictator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictator), you'll find examples of absolute rulers who had set terms. [Roman Dicatators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_dictator) being the original example as well as Giuseppe Garibaldi.

Many states have or have had emergency power laws that effectively result in a dictator for the duration of an emergency (although sometimes this [doesn't go so well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_Fire_Decree), [Article 48](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_48_%28Weimar_Constitution%29))

[Protectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Protector) spring to mind as well.  So do puppet rulers, colonial governors, [Proconsuls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proconsul) and others who ruled like kings but bowed a knee to an external authority.

As for monarchies, recently with Queen Beatrice's abdication we've been reminded of Dutch tradition, where an aged monarch is expected to abdicate. But did you know it was also expected in [Medieval Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdication#In_Japanese_History), where it was practice for emperors to step aside so the heir could ascend relatively young. In addition, before Meiji Restoration it was common for empresses (women) to rule for the minimum time until a male descendant was old enough to rule. Women leaders acting as a temporary "stop-gap". 
None of these aren't hard and fast term limits, but they are clearly informal limits on length of rule.

Comment: Here are some weird traditions to do with temporary monarchs, http://www.bartleby.com/196/64.html haven't verified. (The other side of the dictator coin, temporary ceremonial monarchs, regal yet powerless)

Comment: +1 for the emperor-monks; the other examples are not quite fitting...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, yeah but you can never be sure what people want to get from a question. Also the difference between absolute ruler and monarch isn't huge. Japan is definitely the best example for odd practices, as usual.

Comment: +1 I appreciate the effort, but @Hendrik's answer is more fitting to what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Roman king (rex) had a limited term of 8 years, but this was never observed. The kings manipulated the law to extend their term.

Under Diocletian the Dominate system was established in Roman Empire where an emperor's term was limited to 10 years. But only a few emperors followed this limitation, which soon became obsolete. But it is not certain whether Dominate should be considered a monarchy.

Comment: Way to go for bringing up the Dominate (although it was actually 20 years: 10 as caesar and then 10 as augustus). However, what is your source for the assertion that the rex was limited to 6 years?

Comment: @Felix Goldberg thanks, I fixed the term for Dominate.

Comment: Btw, how is the Dominate not a monarchy? What else can you call rule by one person who gets to designate his successor, wears a crown, and receives proskynesis from everybody? What am I missing?

Comment: @Felix Goldberg, the Soviet Encyclopedia says it was a (military) dictatorship. The crown was not exclusive to the monarch in Rome: there was a civic crown (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civic_Crown) under the Republic. Also the dominate was not hereditary and the head of state was not single. Basically, not a single sign of a monarchy: no single ruler, no inheritance, limited term.

Comment: Guys, if you are going to carry on a debate or discussion, then you need to take it to the chat room. You can leave a message there and then the other person can respond at their convenience, just as you have been doing here. The comments section is not intended for this use. All other comments were deleted, and if you start it up again, future comments will also be deleted.

Comment: @Anixx: Can we discuss this in the chat room? I opened a room (open to everyone) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7430/rex

Comment: @StevenDrennon rather than _deleting_ them, couldn't you _move_ them to the chat? Deleting information is always a bad thing :( or there is not such a feature?

Comment: @Lohoris chat room is temporary, it is anyway removed after a day or two.

Comment: @Anixx oh. I pity. My dislike for the administration of SE would increase, if only it wasn't already capped...

Answer (score -2):

Consider Sparta.

In Sparta the king's (archagestes') term was 8 years. Upon its end, the ephores conducted a fortune-telling rite so to determine whether the gods were in favor of the term extension.

Comment: ...which one would imagine stimulated a rather nice enriching of the ephores coffers.

Comment: What is the source for this? Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartan_Constitution#Dual_Kingship) talks about kingship for life. So apparently does everything I've ever read so far on Sparta. Please explain where this comes from.